# Send email via exim4 using port 587

Tags: email, exim

I have configured exim4 and am trying to send out emails using port 587 and the email is being sent but on the mail server it show connecting at port 25.
I am using:

```bash
echo "Subject:Hello All" | sendmail -v  -port 587 shaheena.kazi@gmail.com


T: remote_smtp for shaheena.kazi@gmail.com
Connecting to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2607:f8b0:4004:c08::1a]:25 ... LOG: MAIN
```

(Not pasting the entire output of the log here)

+++++++++++++++++++++
I wanted to check why the connection goes to port 25 as shown below----
`"""Connecting to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2607:f8b0:4004:c08::1a]:25 ... LOG: MAIN""""`

I want all my email to connect on port 587 as I have requested for port 587.
I have tried most of the settings shown online in the exim4 config file. But still it connects on 25.
Links that I followed but no luck : https://www.fyzix.net/index.php?title=Installing_and_Configuring_Exim4_for_Gmail_SMTP_Relay and https://logs.paulooi.com/enable-smtp-port-587-on-exim.php

Also, any mail server I use... it connects to port 25..

Could anyone help me here ?

Comment: This looks like it's meant for https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Exim server is accepting email at port 587, but when it comes to delivering mail, it is not properly configured to establish a TLS/SSL connection to the destination server -- that's why it is connecting to the non-SSL port 25--. You need to get acquainted with [Exim SSL/TLS configuration](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-encrypted_smtp_connections_using_tlsssl.html), install a digital certificate and configure Exim to require SSL/TLS connections when delivering messages.

Besides, some remote SMTP servers may want to establish secure connections through different ports, like 465, 587 and --yes-- 25. This depends on the local set up of the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found to get this working is to add `port = 587` to the `remote_smtp_smarthost:` section in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/30_exim4-config_remote_smtp_smarthost`

This only works if you're using the split-files config approach, chosen via e.g. `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`. Otherwise you have to edit `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` (same section).

Then run `update-exim4.conf` to generate the final config file (`/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated`).

Then restart the exim daemon, e.g. `systemctl restart exim4`.

(There are probably other/more correct ways to configure this by messing with the `driver` directive or TLS settings, but for some reason it doesn't work out-of-the-box on Debian, even after specifying port 587 in the SMTP url via `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`. The docs are enormous.)

See also https://www.fyzix.net/index.php?title=Installing_and_Configuring_Exim4_for_Gmail_SMTP_Relay